# WordPress - How to disable the sidebar without removing widgets?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

The sidebar disappears from the UI when it is emptied of widgets in the admin, but I was hoping to disable it without removing widgets such that I can turn it back on easily with the same widgets in the same configuration. If I were to try to build such a control in the admin, what would be the best practice way to do this? I'm thinking a customizer option or plugin?

Comment: Question unclear. There is a default toggle sidebar (arrow icon) at the bottom of it.

Comment: Perhaps "disable" is a better word to describe what I'm trying to do?